# Authentication using JWT in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, jwt

what I am trying to do is authenticate my Django project using JWT. 
Firstly i am confused which library i have to install one is **django-jwt-auth** and other one is **djangorestframework-jwt**.

So here is my views.py, in which i have a user model and i want to authenticate when a new user is being generated.

```
class UserDetails(APIView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    users = Users.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')
    serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def options(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return Response()

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have models.py

```
class Users(models.Model):
group_id = models.IntegerField()
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
remember_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
activated = models.IntegerField(default=1)
banned = models.IntegerField(default=0)
ban_reason = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
otp = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField()
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

my url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^api-token-auth/', 'rest_framework_jwt.views.obtain_jwt_token'),
url(r'userdetails/$', UserDetails.as_view()),
```

Now i don't know how to access that api-token-auth. where to put authentication in views.py

and where i ahve to add these settings

```
JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER = 'jwt_auth.utils.jwt_encode_handler'
JWT_DECODE_HANDLER = 'jwt_auth.utils.jwt_decode_handler',
JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER = 'jwt_auth.utils.jwt_payload_handler'
JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER = 'jwt_auth.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler'
JWT_SECRET_KEY: SECRET_KEY
JWT_ALGORITHM = 'HS256'
JWT_VERIFY = True
JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION = True
JWT_LEEWAY = 0
JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA = datetime.timedelta(seconds=300)
JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH = False
JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX = 'Bearer'
```

and some post say i have to this to my settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
),
}
```

So please tell me how to use JWT.

Answer (score 4):

1. You should install `djangorestframework-jwt`
2. Follow steps [here](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)
3. Add this decorators to functions where you want authentication(change GET appropriate to method you are using, add AllowAny to DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES if you want to have views accessible without auth)

   `@api_view(['GET'])
   @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))`
4. Call `api-token-auth/` with username and password to get token
5. Add token to your request headers when calling permisson protected functions: `Authorization: JWT <your_token>"`

All settings must be added to `settings.py` file like described [here](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/)
I see that your `User` model doesn't extend `AbstractUser` or `BaseUser` model. If you want to use JWT auth with Django, in that easy way desribed here, your `User` model should extend one of those models(I suggest AbstractUser). Therfore Django will manage all auth hard-work for you.